# redirect / rewrite specific url only in asp

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I am trying to get my `page.com/here` to redirect to `page.com/?info=here`. I've got the following in my web.config file:

```
    <rewrite>

<rules>


                <rule name="try" stopProcessing="true">
                    <match url="/here$" />
                    <action type="Redirect" url="http://page.com/?info=here" logRewrittenUrl="true" />
                </rule>   

</rules>

</rewrite>
```

However, when I go to `page.com/here` it sends me to my custom 404 page.

Answer (score 0):

View inbound rule. Outbound rule is different.: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/extensions/url-rewrite-module/creating-outbound-rules-for-url-rewrite-module